# sqlite COUNT grouped return 1?

Tags: sqlite, appcelerator

i am trying to count contacts in `sqlite` table `GROUP by msisdn` .

without `GROUP BY msisdn` return 210
with  `GROUP BY msisdn` return 1

```
var queryTotal   = db.execute('SELECT cid , COUNT(*) AS totalFriends FROM contact WHERE deleted = 0 AND synced = 1 GROUP BY msisdn');
var total = queryTotal.fieldByName('totalFriends');

            alert(total);
```

what is the problem here !

Comment: Where did you loop over returned rows?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your query is correct ?

```
 SELECT cid , COUNT(*) AS totalFriends FROM contact WHERE deleted = 0 AND synced = 1 GROUP BY msisdn
```

try with:

```
GROUP BY cid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include msisdn in your selected column:

SELECT **msisdn**, COUNT(*) AS totalFriends FROM contact WHERE deleted = 0 AND synced = 1 GROUP BY **msisdn**